# Jenkins: unable to login with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins

Using Jenkins ver. 1.585 on Ubuntu 12.04

After installing Jenkins, I then proceeded to enable access control for security.

First, I set the `jenkins` user password:

`sudo passwd jenkins`

.. and added the jenkins user to the shadow group:

`sudo usermod -G shadow jenkins`

.. and restarted jenkins:

`sudo service jenkins restart`

Then I set the Jenkins security:

`Manage Jenkins >> Configure global security`

Then checked "Enable security", then selected "Unix user/group database" for the *Security Realm* and selected "Matrix-based security" for *Authorization*, and added the "jenkins" user.

After clicking save, Chrome showed a login dialog that you typically get with http auth. Using the jenkins user and password I was unable to login. Clearing my browser cache and cookies didn't change anything.

When using Firefox, I did not get the login dialog, instead I got the jenkins log in form, and was able to successfully log in using the jenkins user.

Why can't I log in using Chrome? Why is it showing me this login dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed I could log in just fine while in Incognito mode, so I tried deleting my Chrome user (Settings >> Users >> Delete this user), signed back into chrome, and now I can log in to jenkins.

Hopefully this helps others, this took me a long time to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

Did not work in incognito mode for me, but adding a trailing slash to the url, i.e., `[url]/jenkins/`, worked for me.

Comment: I've spent the day swearing at Jenkins. This solved my issue.